# I have a problem with ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, discord

I'm using Visual Studio Code to build a discord bot.
Before I did everything on repl.it. Since then I can keep the bot up even if the computer shutdowns but I went into quite a few problems and decided to switch over from using the cloud. As I was done setting up a basic frame for the bot I ran into a problem from the very first line of code.

`from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler`

For some reason it says the module apscheduler doesn't exist.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316]

(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>pip install apscheduler

Requirement already satisfied: apscheduler in c:\users\alan kim\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.7.0)

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7 in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from apscheduler) (49.2.1)
```

I'm sure apscheduler is already installed and I have no idea why visual studio says it doesn't exist. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does the python interpreter Visual Studio Code is configured to use match the python interpreter that `python` defaults to at your Command Prompt? See [doc for python interpreter in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing **Ctrl+Shift+`** to open a new integrated Terminal in VS Code. If you didn't change the default setting

`"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true`,

the selected interpreter should already be activated in Terminal. Then use `pip show apscheduler` to check if the module exists in current environment. If not, please reinstall again.